# Array index value increment ?i am trying to understand this - count[str.charAt(i)]++

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I'm having this doubt in this line of code, what will be array size when this code is executed:

`count[str.charAt(i)]++`

Comment: Post full snippet, that would help addressing your question.

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi charAt does _not_ return the character position. It returns the character at the position of the index provided

Comment: Please be clear what you need to exactly count string length or anything else?

Comment: I am assuming that you want to know the value of the 'count' array's index after this line of code is executed and not the length of the array

Comment: Whenever asking a question it is a good practice to describe what you are trying to do, what have you tried till now, what is the issue that you are facing. Also go through the link on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score -1):

Is count an array of a numeric type (int, long)?

You're indexing into a string, getting the ASCII character value blindly, and using it to index into another array.

Then incrementing? You may find that you aren't incrementing what you think you are. What are you trying to do? Hmm.

So, like "1" is 31, which is I think perhaps not what you wanted.

Perhaps something more like

Int idx = Integer.parseInt(are.charAt(t)); //gives you 1 instead of 31
count [idx]++

Also -

YOUR ARRAY SIZE WON'T CHANGE BUT YOU ARE HIGHLY LIKELY TO THROW AN EXCEPTION

Comment: It seems to me that the code in the question is counting the frequency of characters. `char` can be used in place of an `int` in Java, and thus can be used to index into an array. Your conversion makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you are counting the occurrence of characters in a string then streaming to a map() closure that updates either an array or a Map would be more efficient memory wise and safer surely? It's unclear what the OP is trying to do apart from throwing exceptions

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-string-find-its-first-non-repeating-character/

Comment: Please find this link ,i am able to find first non occurence alphabet in string.

Comment: Assuming a limited character set (eg ASCII or ISO-8859-1), streaming to a map will not be more memory efficient than using an array, and using a 'map() closure' will have more overhead than the simple solution using a loop (especially if you use an object-based stream).

Comment: Yeah I agree Mark, but in this case i would counsel safety over premature optimization. IMHO. Some developers use native structures for speed, while others use them because they don't know the more advanced data structures in the language - recent graduates who were trained with c come to mind. This is becoming largely speculative anyway, possibly not the clearest question ever asked